# PHP-SOAP Server program shell_exec() restrictions

Tags: php, shell, soap, exec

I am running Centos 8 with Apache and PHP 8.0.7 and all are updated to latest versions.

I can not run shell_exec() from within a SOAP server function to run another PHP script. I confirmed php binary is found and the php script is readable. So I can run shell_exec('cat file.php') but when I try to run shell_exec('php file.php') I get nothing. Nothing is disabled in /etc/php.ini and even if I make a hard or symbolic link to /usr/bin/php it refuses to run. I can not explain why it does not work. I need to do this since there is PHP script I wrote which is a SOAP client to a third party Server who make a query to that service and echoes the XML so that it can be captured by my PHP SOAP Server function with shell_exec().

Comment: "refuses to run" is still a little vague. Are you getting an exception? What does the function call? As the docs note, maybe try `exec` instead to get access to the exit code, or even better, `proc_open` to get access to stdIn, stdOut and stdError

Comment: Also, can you better explain why you can’t just `include` the file?

Comment: I get empty object as a response of the SOAP client. I see no error log entry or anything else. I doubt the script is ever run. I can not include the file since I need the output that it generates to be stored in a variable. So I do $xml = shell_exec('php file.php') but get nothing. If I change it to shell_Exec('cat file.php´) I get the contents of that file.

Comment: If you include the file and it echos, you can capture the output using output buffering techniques, would that work?

Comment: I will try using buffer to capture the output but still I want to know why  "ls -l file.php" works why "cat file.php" worksa, etc. but "php file.php" does not work but works from CLI

Comment: and how can I pass arguments to the file when it is included? I used to call "php file.php arg1 arg2 arg3)